# Do multiple foreign keys make sense?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

can it make sense for one table to have multiple foreign keys?

Suppose I have three tables, `Table A`, `Table B` and `Table C`.  If I think of the tables as objects (and they are mapped to objects in my code), then both Tables A and B have a many to one relationship with Table C. I.e. Table/object A and B can each have many instances of C.  So the way I designed it is that `Table C` points to the primary key in both `Table A` and `Table B`: in other words, `Table C` has 2 foreign keys (a_Id, and b_Id).

**Edit**: I forgot to mention also that `Table A` can have many instances of `Table B`.  So `Table B` has a foreign key into Table A.  If this makes a difference...

I am wondering if this makes sense or is there a better way to do it?  Thanks.

Comment: Do table A and B have a one-to-many relationship too?

Comment: Yes, table A can have multiple instance of table B...sorry i forgot to point that out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fine, but note that it only makes sense if a C always has to have both an A and a B as a pair.

If you just want A's to have C's and B's to have C's, but A and B are otherwise unrelated then you should put the foreign key in A and in B and allow it to be nullable.

Update: after clarification it seems you want two separate relationships: an A can have many Cs, and a B can have many Cs, but a C can only belong to one A or one B.

Solution: It's two separate one-to-many relationships, so create two new tables A_C and B_C, and put the foreign keys there. A_C contains a foreign key to A and a foreign key to C. Similarly for B_C.

Comment: Thanks..I'm a little confused.  I understand your first point: any given instance of C can be related to A OR B (not both).  I couldn't think of a good solution (and just assumed that in the code I would check both columns and use the one that is not null).  Is that what you were getting at with your second point?

Comment: But A is related to many C's.  As an example Table A could be a blog post and table C is a comment.  So each blog post can have many comments.

Comment: @kim: What's B in your example?

Comment: @kim: But one comment won't be associated with more than one post, so in your example it would be simpler to add a FK to the comments table instead of doing it this way.

Comment: @Sheep - yes, thats what I originally proposed in my post: to have 2 FKs in the comments table (one points to table A (which as an example is a blog post)) and another pointing to table B (which is just another object that can have many comments...

Comment: @kim: I think your solution would work. I've updated my answer based on your clarifications to offer an alternative that I think is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I think I understand your solution. However, I am just wondering why you think its cleaner than just having the FK's in table C and having them nullable (so each C will have 1 nonempty FK and 1 null FK)?

Comment: @kim: I think it's a perfectly valid solution, and it will work. I just think it could be confusing. But I can't see anything wrong with it from a technical point of view. The reason why I think it's cleaner with the separate tables is that if you have to add more tables similar to A and B, your table C would have to have more nullable FKs. It seems rather wasteful to have n columns but with only one value set... but with only two it's not a real problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario, of two different tables being referenced by a third, this is also fine. I have tables in my databases that have 3-4 or even more foreign keys. This is provided that the entity always requires all of the references to exist.

Many to many relationships are also implemented as a single table with two (or more) foreign keys, so yes, they do make sense in that context.

See [this article](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html) about implementing this kind of relationship for PHP and MySQL.

Comment: "This is provided that the entity requires all of the references to exist" - so if this requirement is absent, what would you recommend?

Comment: I would create a separate table for each of the columns that does not always exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't formulate the relations between A,B,C objects any other way, it makes perfect sense to define the FKs like you did.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that makes perfect sense.  It is not at all uncommon to have a table with multiple foreign keys to other tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok to do it this way, but maybe that's because I do it this way. In my case, I have a table full of people, and a table full of roles those people can fulfill. Since each person can be in any number of those roles, the simplest way to have it work was to add a third table tracking these relationships.

It's not a great solution, but it's better than adding a new column to the table each time a new role comes along, and having to rewrite the code running those queries each time. And I sure can't think of a better way to handle it!